# Можно ли вставить SVG в письма?

Tags: html, css, svg

Обычные jpg проходят на ура, но все что в svg не отображается. Тестируемый почтовик gmail. Вставляю через img src = "image.svg". В результате картинка не отображается, а  просто как подгружаемый файл

Comment: Ну а почему в `html` не вставляете `svg`? `<svg>........</svg>`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/

Answer (score 1):

**Насчет svg как понял, вам уже подсказали и я вставлю свои 5 копеек :)**

Не проверял, но могу подсказать переконвертировать файл из svg или jpg и т.д. формат base64.
(решение хорошо тем, что вы не используете подгрузку с стороннего сервиса, а просто вставляете картинку в сообщение в виде кода).

**Сервис:**

```
https://www.base64-image.de/
```

Мой когда то сделанный пример:

```
https://codepen.io/AndreyMyP/pen/LeBZxm
```